# Jones(unlink)=phi

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, knot-theory

Somewhat nebulous question: there are many well known "special" values of
the Jones polynomial, especially those at roots of unity. I always run into
one that has unlink value $\phi$ (golden mean) and writhe factor $(-1)^{1/5}$.
Is there something special about it (maybe it's "at the intersection" of
the Lie groups A1 and G2 or whatnot)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some sense this is the smallest possible quantum group, so it's perhaps not surprising that it comes up often.  In fact, if you have only 2 objects, then there are very few possibilities, see Ostrik's paper http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0203255.